Flutter Firebase: How to upload multiple images?
I've this Button to select images:
IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final results = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                allowMultiple: true,
                type: FileType.custom,
                allowedExtensions: ['png', 'jpg'],
              );
              if (results == null) {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                const SnackBar(
                    content: Text("No Image selected")
                ),
                );
                return null;
              }

              final path = results.files.single.path!;
              final fileName = results.files.single.name;
              final docID = widget.docID;

                storage
              .uploadFile(path, fileName, docID)
              .then((value) => print('Done'));
            },

          icon: Icon(),
        ),

...then the upload function:
Future<void> uploadFile(

String filePath,
String fileName,
String docID,
) async {
  File file = File(filePath);
  try {

    await storage.ref('images/test/$docID/$fileName').putFile(file);
  } on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}

This works with single images, now i want to select and upload multiple files. The selecting works already, but how can i upload them?
I tried to save the files as a list, but have no idea how to continue:
List files = results.paths.map((path) => File(path!)).toList();

    IconButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final results = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                    allowMultiple: true,
                    type: FileType.custom,
                    allowedExtensions: ['png', 'jpg'],
                  );
                  if (results == null) {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(
                        content: Text("No Image selected")
                    ),
                    );
                    return null;
                  }
                  final List<String> filePaths = results.paths!;
                  for (String path in filePaths) {
                  final fileName = path.split('/').last;
                  final docID = widget.docID;

                 await storage.uploadFile(path, fileName, docID);
    }
  },
    
              icon: Icon(),
            ),


You can just run the uploadFile multiple times, just make sure to use Future.wait() so that the uploads run in parallel.
Future<List<String>> uploadFiles(List<File> _images) async {
  var imageUrls = await Future.wait(_images.map((_image) => 
  uploadFile(_image)));
  return imageUrls;
}

